# Filter output from python paramiko interactive shell

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using paramiko to SSH into huawei routers and get the output. Here i'm doing the SSH from a jumpserver . So first i have to SSH into jump server.So i have used get_transport() method to ssh from jump server to Huawei router. Since this is a huawei router i have to use invoke_shell() method to get the command output. My problem is that i'm getting all the information from the shell output For example i get the banner while connecting to router from jumpserver and hostname of the router and command applied ( not only the command output ). So how do i filter command output?

```
import time
import paramiko
import csv

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect('10.X.X.X',22, username='user', password='password')

vmtransport = ssh.get_transport()
dest_addr = ('10.Y.Y.Y', 22)
local_addr = ('10.X.X.X', 22)
vmchannel = vmtransport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)




client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('10.Y.Y.Y', username='user', password='password', sock=vmchannel)


commands = client.invoke_shell()       # Request an interactive shell session on this channel.

commands.send("display clock\n")
time.sleep(1)
output = commands.recv(65535)
output = output.decode("utf-8")


print(output)
```

Comment: Try using https://pypi.org/project/paramiko-expect/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I did was skipping lines till I get to the required output.

```
lines_to_be_skipped = 4    
lines = output.strip().split('\n')[lines_to_be_skipped:]
```